# How can I call an already defined function on a focus event?

Tags: jquery, function, focus, bind

So i have this code:

```
function myOnFocus(){
    $('tr').css("background-color","white");
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","blue");
}

$(".priority").focus(myOnFocus());
```

How can i call myOnFocus() with jquery .focus() event but without writing the whole function between those two parantheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".priority").focus(myOnFocus);
```

using the `()` calls the function ..

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `()` 
from

```
$(".priority").focus(myOnFocus());
```

to

```
$(".priority").focus(myOnFocus);
```

Comment: hahahahha it worked thanks ;)... i tried everything from bind and every syntax imaginable.... so funny that it was so simple